# Worklight: JsonStore behaviour on hard install of new version

Tags: json, updates, ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I am not sure about if we release **new version of App** on App Store and users get it installed. Now in this case, the **existing JSONStore data of previous version of the App, Will be there or will be wiped out**?

If it remains then good, otherwise what workaround we can do here. Any suggestions, please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that asking on StackOverflow is **not** a replacement for rigorous [unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing), [functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_testing), etc. tests and having [quality assurance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quality_assurance) as part of your development processes. I would advice you test this if you're not already: install the Worklight Application from the App Store, then upgrade to the new version and check if everything is still working... before going into production.

As long as you don't change your collections' metadata (name, search fields, additional search fields, etc.) JSONStore should keep working fine when you upgrade.

Comment: Yes, I am doing different testings but tried to get some feedback on this. Thanks

Comment: If the answer was helpful, consider clicking on the up arrow and/or green check mark =]